How to collapse similar looking recipes without using automatic variables in Makefile
This is the piece of Makefile I'm referring to:
$(API1): $(OBJDIR)/$(API1)/$(API1_FILES).o
    @mkdir -p $(APISDIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$@/*.o -o $(APISDIR)/$@
    @printf "$(_SUCCESS) $(GREEN)- $@ maked!\n$(RESET)"

$(API2): $(OBJDIR)/$(API2)/$(API2_FILES).o
    @mkdir -p $(APISDIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$@/*.o -o $(APISDIR)/$@
    @printf "$(_SUCCESS) $(GREEN)- $@ maked!\n$(RESET)"

$(API3): $(OBJDIR)/$(API3)/$(API3_FILES).o
    @mkdir -p $(APISDIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$@/*.o -o $(APISDIR)/$@
    @printf "$(_SUCCESS) $(GREEN)- $@ maked!\n$(RESET)"

...

in which the variables API1, API2, API3 are the names of apis that I want to compile autonomously, and API1_FILES, ... API3_FILES are the names of the files (without .cpp extenision) needed for each api, including one main() function for each file list.
Everything is working fine, but I really wanted to collapse some of this, especially because the recipes are the same for each api.
Are there some obscure methods, like a variable loop for recipes or something? Or any other way to recover the current recipe name (as with $@)?
I made new varialbes
APIS         = $(API1) $(API2) $(API3) #...
APIS_FILES   = $(API1_FILES) $(API2_FILES) $(API3_FILES) #...

and tried something like
$(APIS): $(OBJDIR)/$@/$(APIS_FILES).o
    @mkdir -p $(APISDIR)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/$@/*.o -o $(APISDIR)/$@
    @printf "$(_SUCCESS) $(GREEN)- $@ maked!\n$(RESET)"

that would be working for each api, were only automatic variables expanded in the prerequisites line, which aren't.
I am not worried about the compilation of all files from API_FILES, since I can simply check the existence of the .cpp file in the source folder.

For the record, the correct English past participle of "make" is "made".

The $@ only gets expanded at execution time inside a recipe. You are looking for %, but you seem to be saying you don't want that?

It cannot be true that the above is "working fine" if things are as you describe.  Since you didn't actually show the values of API1_FILES etc. we can't know but you allude to them containing multiple filenames.  Because if API1_FILES contains foo bar baz (and OBJDIR is obj and API1 is api1) then $(OBJDIR)/$(API1)/$(API1_FILES).o expands to obj/api1/foo bar baz.o which is clearly wrong.

Also, it's always wrong to build any target other than the one you told make you'd build, so -o $(APISDIR)/$@ is wrong.  You want just -o $@.  And, you can use $^ to represent the list of prerequisites (object files) and $(@D) to represent the directory containing the target.

What is your objection to automatic variables?  And how is that consistent with the fact that you're using one ($@) fairly heavily in your recipes?  Or alternatively, what does "automatic variable" mean to you?

You will have to use the eval function for this.
First create a variable containing the rule you want; unfortunately you have to escape all the variables except the one you want to expand immediately:
convert = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/$($1)/%.o,$($1_FILES))

define API_RULE
$1: $$(call convert,$1)
        @mkdir -p $$(@D)
        @$$(CXX) $$(CXXFLAGS) $$^ -o $$@
        @printf "$$(_SUCCESS) $$(GREEN)- $$@ made!\n$$(RESET)"
endef

Then you can invoke it once for each variable you want to expand:
$(foreach V,API1 API2 API3,$(eval $(call API_RULE,$V)))

Note this is not tested.  If you want to see what's happening you can write the foreach line again replacing info for eval to see what make sees:
$(foreach V,API1 API2 API3,$(info $(call API_RULE,$V)))

